# How to make a JavaScript class constructor for an HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, class, constructor, this

I have a function `element()` that I use to create new elements.

function element(name, className, attributes, innerText) {

```
function element(name, className, attributes, innerText) {

    const element = document.createElement(name);
    element.setAttribute("class", className);

    if (attributes) {

        Object.keys(attributes).forEach(attr => {
            element.setAttribute(attr, attributes[attr]);
        });

    }

    if (innerText) element.innerText = innerText;

    return element;

}
```

How would I convert this function into a class constructor? This is my idea:

```
class Element {

    constructor (name, className, attributes, innerText) {

        this = document.createElement(name);
        this.setAttribute("class", className);

        if (attributes) {
            
            Object.keys(attributes).forEach(attr => {
                this.setAttribute(attr, attributes[attr]);
            });

        };

        if (innerText) this.innerText = innerText;

    };

}
```

But this is throwing an error since I can't assign a value to `this`. How do I fix this?

Comment: `this.element`?

Comment: It's a bad idea to return something else than `this` from a class constructor.